# SVG for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android

[image]

how to customize the vector size for multiple screen sizes button like 330dp and 440dp sizes

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/soundSwitch"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sounddrawable"


        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"

        />
```

Comment: Use dimension files

Comment: @KlingKlang can you elobrate it

Comment: dimension files are resources which let you have specific sets of dimensions depending on the resource bucket (i.e.: dpending on the device density)

Comment: @KlingKlang  resource dimension i got it thanks ...